# Visual Composer not parsing

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I just installed a theme I bought for wordpress and I installed dummy data.
The istructions said I should install the visual composer plugin so I am assuming that is was built that way.
But when I open pages that it came with, it doesn't parse nicely. 
i have 1 page, that when I open it in visual composer the entire page shows up in 1 box that says raw html data.

But when i try to view it in classic mode, all I saw is gibberish letters and numbers

There is another page, that looks like the rows are split properly. But all the boxes say 'text box' instead it should be a bannervideo editing box.
when I view it in classic mode , it looks more like visual composer code

```
[vc_row][vc_column][bannervideo title="Atena Excellence in teaching"  desc="College / University / Campus" 
text1="Take a tour" link1="#" text2="View courses" link2="#" 
play="Play video" image="184" link="https://vimeo.com/20370747" linkmp4="/intro.mp4" linkogv="huploads/2016/01/intro.ogv"]
[/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Did I do something wrong when importing dummy data, or is it a problem with my visual composer?

or am I supposed to be using a different rendering plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your theme miss map for 'bannervideo' shortcode. You should contact to theme author to fix that or provide plugin define the map for that element.

Other option for page builder is King Composer. It is works well with any website https://wordpress.org/plugins/kingcomposer/